# Morphisms of constant rank in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-topology

There is a somewhat loose dictionary between algebro-geometric notions and differential-topological ones. especially if we restrain to the domain of smooth algebraic varieties.

We have notions of a closed embedding of smooth varieties and smooth/etale morphisms of smooth varieties, which might be thought of as counterparts of smooth embeddings and submersions/local diffeomorphisms in the smooth category.

Now is there an analogue of the notion of a map of constant rank, that is such a morphism for which the differential has constant rank at every point?

A nice consequence in differential topology is that then the fibers of this map are smooth submanifolds. In algebraic geometry I am only aware of theorems which assume submersivity to guarantee smooth fibers.

And if there is no such analogues, what is the reason for this difference between smooth and algebraic categories?

Comment: This might not be exactly what you are looking for, but the concept of [flatness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_morphism) is often useful in algebraic geometry. In particular, if $f:X\to Y$ is flat and $X,Y$ are smooth, then the fibres $f^{-1}(y)$ all have the same dimension.

Comment: @Spenser, sure, but I am more looking for the smoothness of fibers.